# Sort an array on the basis of value and get first n elements as an other array of sorted array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with 60 elements in it, which need to be sorted (from low to high) and have to get first 10 elements of that sorted array as another array. I am stuck . any help would be great !

So far I have -

```
$lists_store = get_stores($user_location);
    asort($lists_store); // this give me sorted array as expected 

 echo "<pre>";
print_r($lists_store);
exit;
```

will output ..

```
Array
(
    [39] => 6291
    [52] => 6293
    [63] => 6322
    [64] => 6323
    [46] => 6327
    [37] => 6338
    [26] => 6341
    [44] => 6346
    [20] => 6346
    [17] => 6346
    [11] => 6349
    [43] => 6349
    [24] => 6350
    [21] => 6351
    [12] => 6351
    [10] => 6352
    [27] => 6354
    [22] => 6354
    [19] => 6355 .....
```

Now problem comes here ..

```
    $lists_store = array_slice($lists_store, 0, 10); // gives me first 10 elements of array but on the key basis 

 echo "<pre>";
print_r($lists_store);
exit;
```

will output ..

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6291
    [1] => 6293
    [2] => 6322
    [3] => 6323
    [4] => 6327
    [5] => 6338
    [6] => 6341
    [7] => 6346
    [8] => 6346
    [9] => 6346
)
```

Desired Output --

```
Array
(
    [39] => 6291
    [52] => 6293
    [63] => 6322
    [64] => 6323
    [46] => 6327
    [37] => 6338
    [26] => 6341
    [44] => 6346
    [20] => 6346
    [17] => 6346
)
```

Comment: `lists_store = array_chunk($lists_store, 10, true);`

Comment: Have you read the *documentation* for [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk)?!

Comment: i updated my question , i am using array_slice , and result i mentioned here are also of array_slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `array_chunk()`, use [`array_slice()`](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) with the third parameter "`preserve_keys`".

See the fiddle here: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/0dr-jht

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get the part of array, i think you should use `array_slice`.

> Note that array_slice() will reorder and reset the numeric array
>   indices by default. You can change this behaviour by setting
>   preserve_keys to TRUE.

try using

```
$lists_store = array_slice($lists_store, 0, 10, true);
```

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: Sorry for that i updated my question , I am using array_slice only which is resetting keys

Comment: you should set the fourth parameter to true to preserve the keys.

Answer (score 2):

<s>the documentation on [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) indicates that there's a third optional boolean argument to preserve the key, so if you do:</s>

```
$lists_store = array_chunk($lists_store, 10, true);
```

it might work as you expected

but you should really use [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) as `array_chunk()` divides the array into fragments, `array_slice()` just takes the designated part, which fits more for what you are looking for

```
$lists_store = array_slice($lists_store, 0, 10, true); // the last parameter is used to preserve the keys
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )

The last parameter if set "true" then your keys will be preserved.